# Custom Element Directive is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have created angularjs custom element directive. For some reason i cannot get data from directive. Below is my application folder structure image

*Application Folder Structure*

[image]

**directive.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('mymod')
     .directive('myDirective', function () {
         return {
             restrict: 'E', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
             scope: true,

             templateUrl:'Views/Directives/Header/mytemplate.html',
             controller: 'controller',
             controllerAs: 'vm' 
         }
     });

})();
```

**Controller.js (This is directive's controller)**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mymod')
        .controller('controller', controller);

    controller.$inject = ['$location']; 

    function controller($location) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'controller';

        activate();

        function activate() { }
    }
})();
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
<div>
    Hello Directive
</div>
```

**On Main html Page calling the directive**

```
   <my-Directive></my-Directive>
```

Comment: Does the Hello Directive show up on the screen? You probably shouldn't have an empty scope:{} object in the directive, just set scope = true if you want to use controller/parent scope

Comment: Even after setting `scope=true` does not show my directive's data

Comment: Anything in the console? you have the directive js file linked to the page?

Comment: Also you need full path to mytemplate.html

Comment: nothing...I guess I did not link directive.js to the page

Comment: I've update template URL in above question. still same...i have also linked directive.js to main page

Comment: have you defined mymod somewhere else, i.e. angular.module('mymod', []);

Comment: I have defined as `(function () {
    angular.module('mymod', ["ngRoute"]);
})();
`

Comment: Directive declaration name `myDirective` would translate into `<my-directive>` in HTML, perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Tried that still no luck

Comment: I believe you also need the controller property set when you're using controllerAs, and if you're going to use controllerAs it's normally to rename it, i.e.:
    controller: 'controller',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
then you would use vm and not controller

Comment: did that but still not working. Updated question

Comment: I've done a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/59AVNkNmE0bPHy1fkMXH?p=preview) with your question and is working perfectlly. Your problem could be the angularjs version? Which one are you using? If not, should be something related with including js files in the index/main html. Try to update the plunker and reproduce your error there, that would be helpful.

Comment: @The.Bear Thanks for your solution on plunker. It works well now but I did not do anything. I just closed and reopened visual studio it works excellent. Anyways thanks for your help